# configure xdebug ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php, xdebug

I can't seem to get Apache 2.4 to load my `xdebug` configuration. I've added:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
remote_enable=on
```

to `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`.

According to `phpinfo()` that file does get parsed, but `remote_enable` is still off.

I don't see any errors in the logs. What else might I be missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [xdebug manual](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings):

> xdebug.remote_enable Type: boolean, Default value: 0
>
> This switch
> controls whether Xdebug should try to contact a debug client which is
> listening on the host and port as set with the settings
> xdebug.remote_host and xdebug.remote_port. If a connection can not be
> established the script will just continue as if this setting was 0.

I order to setup remote debugging, you should change your `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` and add this line:

```
  zend_extension=/path/to/your/xdebug.so 
  xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

You should setup xdebug.remote_port and xdebug.remote_host too.

Read this [link](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) for more information on Remote Debugging